# Валидация формы Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Создал модельку, в `rules` указал:

```
return [ 
    [['login', 'password'], 'required']
];
```

Далее во `view` создал `ActiveForm`, поле с вводом пароля и кнопку:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'post', 'action' => ['log-in']]);
$form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput();
Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

Если оставить поле пароля пустым, и кликнуть "Сохранить", никакой ошибки не возникнет (т.е. валидация на стороне клиента не сработает). Как решить эту проблему и сделать так, чтобы форма валидировалась на стороне клиента согласно `rules`?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$validateOnSubmit-detail